# how to add row values to jtable in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a **jcombo box** which has some items like **"schoolbooks","collegebooks","historybooks"**.and i have dynamic **ArrayList object of corresponding books**...**When i click the combo box item "schoolbooks" or "historybooks" ,it should display the contents in JTable from the arraylist**.while every action performing,the JTable has to display the contents of the corresponding item  of 'schoolbooks' or 'historybooks' .it ***should not append new rows when every action is performing*** ...i have used **default table model** in this.but when i **add 3 or 4 rows  using default table model**,its appending the row with previous here..**if i use removeRow(i) in for loop** ,its **removing 1 row or 2 rows** only...**Its not removing previous all rows suppose if i have 7 rows** ..i am not able to solve this..please if anyone know this,please help...

Answer (score 3):

You might want to review [*How to Use Tables*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) as a guide to preparing your [sscce](http://sscce.org/). As you are using `DefaultTableModel`, you'll need to show how you construct the `Object[]` passed to `addRow()` and how you calculate the index passed to `removeRow()`.

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519244/jar-bundler-using-osxadapter-causing-application-to-lag-or-terminate/7519403#7519403).

Answer (score 1):

> if i use removeRow(i) in for loop ,its removing 1 row or 2 rows only...Its not removing previous all rows suppose if i have 7 rows

When you remove multiple rows you need to remove the row from the end of the table down to 0:

```
for (int i = table.getRowCount() - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    // add logic here
}
```