# JAR Bundler using OSXAdapter causing application to lag or terminate

Tags: java, macos, swing, jarbundler

I've created a simple Java application that each second for for 10 seconds consecutive seconds adds a new row to a `JTable`. It consists of three classes.

**The main class that gets called once the program is started**

```
public class JarBundlerProblem {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.err.println("Initializing controller");
        new Controller();
    }
}
```

**A controller that creates the GUI and alters it through `doWork()`**

```
public class Controller {
    public Controller()
    {
        doWork(null);
    }
    public static void doWork(String s)
    {
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            gui.addRow("Line "+(i+1));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And finally, the GUI**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class GUI {
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    private JTable table = new JTable(model);
    private JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
    
    public GUI()
    {
        model.addColumn("Name");
        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void addRow(String name)
    {
        model.addRow(new Object[]{name});
    }
}
```

Since I'm developing for OS X, and I need to be able to associate my application with a certain file type (let's say `.jarbundlerproblem`), I have to bundle my `JAR` file into an `APP` using [Apple Jar Bundler](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Conceptual/Jar_Bundler/Introduction/Introduction.html). I have done this successfully, my application opens, counts to ten, writing out each second.

## Now, for the problem

By default, double-clicking a `.jarbundlerproblem`, and associating the file with my application, will not pass the file I double-clicked as an argument to the application. Apparently, this is just Java on OS X works.

Since I need to be able to see what file was double-clicked, I'm using [OSXAdapter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/OSXAdapter/Introduction/Intro.html) which is a Java library made by Apple for the purpose. This, I've implemented by altering the constructor of my `Controller` class and added another method `registerForMacOSXEvents()`:

```
public Controller()
{
    registerForMacOSXEvents();
    //doWork(null);
}
public void registerForMacOSXEvents() {
    try {
        OSXAdapter.setFileHandler(this, getClass().getDeclaredMethod("doWork", new Class[] { String.class }));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error while loading the OSXAdapter:");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But after this (minor) modification, my application starts acting up. Sometimes, it doesn't open, even though I can see in the Console that it just started (`Initializing controller` is written), but after a few attempts, it will eventually start, but the windows will be completely blank for the first 10 seconds, and after that, the 10 rows will be added.

## Help

Now, I've struggled with this quite a bit, and it seems like there isn't a lot of documentation regarding neither OSXAdapter nor Jar Bundler. What am I doing wrong? Or shouldn't I be using OSXAdapter or Jar Bundler in the first place?

Comment: just to make sure I understand the OSXAdapter (not familiar with mac): basically it's a thread running - outside of your control - which reports its results by messaging the doWork with a string (filename?) until its ready, starting immediately after registration? How does it signal being ready?

Comment: glad to help :-) Would you please show your solution (without the pending list)?

Comment: @kleopatra I don't know exactly how `OSXAdapter` works, I've just only familiarized myself with it. If you're interested in knowing more about it, its source is available at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/OSXAdapter/Listings/src_OSXAdapter_java.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000685-src_OSXAdapter_java-DontLinkElementID_5

Comment: @kleopatra My solution is done by taking your idea and implementing it into my application which is a lot more code than what is presented above, so showing my solution will be difficult. I can explain what I've done though: All the work that you had in `run()` I've moved to `doInBackground()`, and instead added `execute()`to `run()`. `doWork()` has been removed completely. Whenever an iteration in `Controller.doInBackground()` is done, it just calls `publish()`.

Comment: hmm ... dont quite get it, but if it's working :-) Just beware: the doc states that a SwingWorker is designed to execute once - there might be side-effects if you invoke that repeatedly

Comment: The point is that you're doing all the work in `run()`, then calling `doWork()` and have that call `doInBackground()`. There is no need for three methods; one will suffice. Additionally, if the `Thread.sleep()` is removed from `doInBackground()`, the `while` loop might stop and `doInBackground()` terminates, so the last rows won't get published to the GUI. This can no longer occur either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing it, I'm not fully convinced a SwingWorker is a simpler (aka: better) solution - still requires additional thread synching (between the worker thread and the "outer" thread which passes in the file/names). Anyway (taking the opportunity to learn, and be it by errors :), below is a crude proof of concept example for the basic idea:

- implement the Controller as SwingWorker, which funnels the input from the outer thread into the EDT
- make it accept input (from the adapter, f.i.) via a method doWork(..) which queues the input for publishing
- implement doInBackground to succesively publish the input

open issues

- synch the access to the local list (not an expert in concurrency, but pretty sure that needs to be done)
- reliably detecting the end of the outer thread (here simply stops when the input queue is empty)

Feedback welcome :-)

```
public class GUI {
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    private JTable table = new JTable(model);
    private JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);

    public GUI() {
        model.addColumn("Name");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void addRow(String name) {
        model.addRow(new Object[] { name });
    }

    /**
     * Controller is a SwingWorker.
     */
    public static class Controller extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {
        private GUI gui;

        private List<String> pending;

        public Controller() {
            gui = new GUI();
        }

        public void doWork(String newLine) {
            if (pending == null) {
                pending = new ArrayList<String>();
                pending.add(newLine);
                execute();
            } else {
                pending.add(newLine);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            while (pending.size() > 0) {
                publish(pending.remove(0));
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * @inherited <p>
         */
        @Override
        protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
            for (String object : chunks) {
                gui.addRow(object);
            }
        }

    }

    /** 
     * Simulating the adapter.
     * 
     *  Obviously, the real-thingy wouldn't have a reference 
     *  to the controller, but message the doWork refectively 
     */
    public static class Adapter implements Runnable {

        Controller controller;

        public Adapter(Controller controller) {
            this.controller = controller;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
            {
                controller.doWork("Line "+(i+1));
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.err.println("Initializing controller");
        new Adapter(new Controller()).run();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName());
}
```

Comment: +1 Re open issues: using `synchronized` on `doWork()` should be sufficient, and the `get()` method of `SwingWorker` will wait until its background thread exits. I've added continuous [variation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519244/jar-bundler-using-osxadapter-causing-application-to-lag-or-terminate/7568947#7568947) nearby.

Comment: Thanks, kleopatra, using your example I finally managed to get it all working. I did, however separate the classes and move all the work into `doInBackground` and got rid of the `pending` list all together.

Comment: I agree that `SwingWorker` is the better choice; it sounds like there's no need for a pending queue.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you're blocking the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)(EDT). [`SwingWorker`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637215/can-a-progress-bar-be-used-in-a-class-outside-main/4637725#4637725) would be a better choice, but this example implements `Runnable`.

Addendum: You might look at this [project](http://robotchase.sourceforge.net/) for an example of [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) architecture. It also shows how to construct a Mac OS application bundle without using JAR Bundler. More on MVC may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066590/gui-problem-after-rewriting-to-mvc/3072979#3072979).

As an aside, this example shows one approach to auto-scrolling a `JTable`. Click on the thumb to suspend scrolling; release to resume.

Addendum: Your application lags for 10 seconds on startup. As this is the exact time for which the `Controller` sleeps, it's surely sleeping on the EDT. An [sscce](http://sscce.org/) would be dispositive. Instead, do the work on another thread and update the model on the EDT. `SwingWorker` has a `process()` method that does so automatically, or you can use `invokeLater()` as shown below. Until your application is correctly synchronized, there's little hope of getting Apple events to work.

Addendum: You can invoke [`isDispatchThread()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#isDispatchThread%28%29) in the `Controller` to check. The project cited includes a `.dmg` with a Mac application and an `ant` file that builds the bundle *in situ* via target `dist2`.

Addendum: See also the alternate approaches shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10461026/230513).

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentEvent;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/** @seehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519244 */
public class TableAddTest extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    private static final int N_ROWS = 8;
    private static String[] header = {"ID", "String", "Number", "Boolean"};
    private DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(null, header) {

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
            return getValueAt(0, col).getClass();
        }
    };
    private JTable table = new JTable(dtm);
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    private JScrollBar vScroll = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
    private JProgressBar jpb = new JProgressBar();
    private int row;
    private boolean isAutoScroll;

    public TableAddTest() {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        jpb.setIndeterminate(true);
        this.add(jpb, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        Dimension d = new Dimension(320, N_ROWS * table.getRowHeight());
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(d);
        for (int i = 0; i < N_ROWS; i++) {
            addRow();
        }
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        vScroll.addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {

            @Override
            public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
                isAutoScroll = !e.getValueIsAdjusting();
            }
        });
        this.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Add Row") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                addRow();
            }
        }));
        this.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private void addRow() {
        char c = (char) ('A' + row++ % 26);
        dtm.addRow(new Object[]{
                Character.valueOf(c),
                String.valueOf(c) + String.valueOf(row),
                Integer.valueOf(row),
                Boolean.valueOf(row % 2 == 0)
            });
    }

    private void scrollToLast() {
        if (isAutoScroll) {
            int last = table.getModel().getRowCount() - 1;
            Rectangle r = table.getCellRect(last, 0, true);
            table.scrollRectToVisible(r);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    addRow();
                }
            });
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    scrollToLast();
                }
            });
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000); // simulate latency
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.err.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                TableAddTest nlt = new TableAddTest();
                f.add(nlt);
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
                new Thread(nlt).start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect the bundling simply exposes the latent synchronization problem.

Comment: Could you explain how to do this if `addRow()` isn't called from within the GUI class?

Comment: @Kristian: Move the update method into your `TableModel` subclass, and pass a reference to the model via the external `Runnable`'s constructor.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. My update method? Do you mean `GUI.addRow()`? And do you want me to override the `addRow()` method of `model`? You lost me.

Comment: You can override the model's `addRow()`, but I'd prefer composition. Keep the model and view separate, as discussed in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066590/gui-problem-after-rewriting-to-mvc/3072979#3072979).

Comment: @trashgod: How would overriding the `DefaultTableModel.addRow()` help at all? The problem is that method doesn't get called when it should. And yes, I would also prefer to keep it seperated, I love the MVC pattern, but I still don't get what you suggest I do with my application.

Comment: No, you say I'm doing work on EDT, which I'm not. All work is done in Controller. Additionally, you come with a suggestion of making an OS X Application without JAR Bundler, but the project you link to is just JAR files; an unbundled application, which means it doesn't involve OSXAdapter that I depend on.

Comment: I believe you are mistaken on both counts; more above.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen what you are doing wrong is the _access_ of the ui _off_ the EDT. All change _must_ happen on the EDT, no exception to the rule. Trashgod shows how to do it with invokeLater, another (in your context better option, IMO) is implementing a SwingWorker - read its api doc to see an example which fits perfectly to your problem.

Comment: See also the alternate approaches shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10461026/230513).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variation of @kleopatra's [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519244/jar-bundler-using-osxadapter-causing-application-to-lag-or-terminate/7567436#7567436) in which a continuously running `Controller` accepts new entries in `doWork()`, while a `SwingWorker` processes the `pending` entries asynchronously in its background thread. [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) handles the synchronization.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class GUI {

    private static final Random rnd = new Random();
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    private JTable table = new JTable(model);
    private JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);

    public GUI() {
        model.addColumn("Name");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void addRow(String name) {
        model.addRow(new Object[]{name});
    }

    /**
     * Controller is a SwingWorker.
     */
    private static class Controller extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

        private static final int MAX = 5;
        private GUI gui;
        private BlockingQueue<String> pending =
            new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(MAX);

        public Controller() {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    gui = new GUI();
                }
            });
        }

        private void doWork(String newLine) {
            try {
                pending.put(newLine);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            while (true) {
                // may block if nothing pending
                publish(pending.take());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(rnd.nextInt(500)); // simulate latency
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
            for (String object : chunks) {
                gui.addRow(object);
            }
        }
    }

    /** 
     * Exercise the Controller.
     */
    private static class Adapter implements Runnable {

        private Controller controller;

        private Adapter(Controller controller) {
            this.controller = controller;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            controller.execute();
            int i = 0;
            while (true) {
                // may block if Controller busy
                controller.doWork("Line " + (++i));
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(rnd.nextInt(500)); // simulate latency
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Initializing controller");
        // Could run on inital thread via
        // new Adapter(new Controller()).run();
        // but we'll start a new one
        new Thread(new Adapter(new Controller())).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I completely removed the `pending` from my actual project. :-)

Comment: thanks - ArrayBlockingQueue is my learn item of the day :-) and +1 for creating the ui on the EDT, my forgetfulness is legendary ...

Comment: @kleopatra: I always welcome your insights. I'm glad you found `ArrayBlockingQueue` interesting. I've updated the code to use the interface, [`BlockingQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html), which has implementations for a variety of use cases.