# Lock JScrollPane to bottom of JTextArea (java swing)

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I currently have a setup where I have a `JTextArea` inside a `JScrollPane` so that you can scroll though the text in the box.

What I would like to do is set the `JScrollPane` up so that whenever new text is added to the box (always at the bottom on a new line) it will scroll down to the bottom.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

**Please note:** I don't want it to be permanently locked onto the bottom (users should still be able to scroll through the text), just when text is being updated. I'm after an effect like when you tail a log file in UNIX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not simply set the caret position to the end of the JTextArea. i.e.,

```
myTextArea.setCaretPosition(myTextArea.getDocument().getLength());
```

Comment: +1 [Text Area Scrolling](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/text-area-scrolling/) offers convenient alternatives, but this might be the easiest way to control scrolling as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938881/lock-jscrollpane-to-bottom-of-jtextarea-java-swing/7939508#7939508).

Answer (score 3):

> I don't want it to be permanently locked onto the bottom

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519244/jar-bundler-using-osxadapter-causing-application-to-lag-or-terminate/7519403#7519403) uses an `AdjustmentListener` to suspend auto-scrolling when the mouse is held down in the scroll bar's thumb. As soon as the thumb is released, auto-scrolling resumes.  You can adapt this to `JTextArea` using the [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938881/lock-jscrollpane-to-bottom-of-jtextarea-java-swing/7938934#7938934) suggested by @Hovercraft.

Answer (score 1):

I use this code and JTextArea go to the bottom on adding text

```
((DefaultCaret) jTextArea1.getCaret()).setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
```