# Unable to use custom renderer

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I am trying to create custom cell renderer for jTable. And I would admit, even with so much reading I havent really been able to understand how to add custom components as cell renderer. I want to add `JCheckBox` renderer.

So far I have tried this code:

```
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class test extends JFrame {
    public static DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    public static void main (String args[]){
    JTable table = new JTable();
    table.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, new CheckboxTableCellRenderer());
    table.setModel(model);
    model.addRow(new Object[] {"testData2","testData1"});
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(list);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}



public static class CheckboxTableCellRenderer<E> extends JCheckBox implements
 TableCellRenderer {

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent( JTable table,
        Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
        int row, int column ){
     setComponentOrientation(table.getComponentOrientation());

     setFont(table.getFont());
     setText(String.valueOf(value));

     setBackground(table.getBackground());
     setForeground(table.getForeground());

     setSelected(isSelected);
     setEnabled(table.isEnabled());

     return this;
}

}
}
```

But no matter what row I try to add to model, it doesnt show any data in table.

Can anyone show me a correct way to do this?

Comment: Why not use the default renderer/editor for `Boolean.class`, as shown in this possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8739207/230513)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working example:

```
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class test extends JFrame {
    public static DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, 4) {
      public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex == 2 || columnIndex == 3) {
          return Boolean.class;
        } else {
          return Object.class;
        }
      }
    };
    public static void main (String args[]){
      JTable table = new JTable();
      table.setDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class, new CheckboxTableCellRenderer());
      model.addRow(new Object[] {"testData2","testData1",false,true});
      table.setModel(model);
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
      frame.setSize(640,480);
      frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static class CheckboxTableCellRenderer<E> extends JCheckBox implements
     TableCellRenderer {

      @Override
      public Component getTableCellRendererComponent( JTable table,
              Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
              int row, int column ){
           setComponentOrientation(table.getComponentOrientation());

           setFont(table.getFont());

            if (!isSelected) {
              setBackground(table.getBackground());
              setForeground(table.getForeground());
            } else {
              setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
              setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
            }


           setSelected((Boolean) value);
           setEnabled(table.isEnabled());

           return this;
      }

    }

}
```

You only want the custom renderer for `Boolean.class`, but `DefaultTableModel` only returns `Object.class`, hence an override for `getColumnClass`. Might also need to specify the number of columns, see the constructor call.

`isSelected` is not about the value in the cell but rather if the cell/row is selected and should be displayed in reverse (or otherwise) colors.

Also added a `JScrollPane`, might not be needed.

Editing still looks weird, you might need to define a custom editor as well but not sure.

Edit: if, as per @trashgod's suggestion, we just drop the `setDefaultRenderer()` call, it looks pretty good.

Comment: I think the reason he extended `JCheckBox` was so that he wouldn't have to instantiate a new one every time or cache one explicitly. I suppose as long as he returns a `Component`, he's fine.