# How to copy & delete checkbox checked rows between two jTables

Tags: java, jtable

I'm trying to solve this issue since past three days. I'm new to Java world. My task is,

There are two tables T1 and T2.
T1's first column is checkbox.
As soon as checkbox in T1 the selected row should be copied to T2.And also when I uncheck the checkbox, it should automatically remove the selected row from T2.
There is no button action here only mouse release event.

```
private void setTotalAmounts() {
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) BillRedemptionTable.getModel();
    DefaultTableModel model1 = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();
    int checkeditemno = 0;
    int rownum[] = BillRedemptionTable.getSelectedRows();
    for (int i = 0; i < rownum.length; i++) {
        boolean isChecked;
        isChecked = (Boolean) BillRedemptionTable.getValueAt(rownum[i], 1);
        if (isChecked) {
            try {
                checkeditemno++;
                //fetch values from first table rows
                int billno = Integer.parseInt((String) model.getValueAt(rownum[i], 2));                    
                int billamount = Integer.parseInt((String) model.getValueAt(rownum[i], 4));
                String artype = (String) model.getValueAt(rownum[i], 5);
                //add the above values to second table row
                model1.addRow(new Object[]{billno, billamount, artype});
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        } else if (!isChecked) {
            //this code is to remove rows from second table where checkboxes unchecked in the first table
            for (int j = 0; j < jTable2.getRowCount(); j--) {
                model1.removeRow(rownum[i]);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This is the code i'm using currently.

Can any one help me out here...

[when checking the chekboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93twO.png)

[when unchecking one row (row number 8)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bVXZ.png)

When unchecked one row, I got the below error in Netbeans  IDE

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 2
    at java.util.Vector.removeElementAt(Vector.java:558)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.removeRow(DefaultTableModel.java:462)
    at org.pawnshop.ui.BillRedemption.setTotalAmounts(BillRedemption.java:118)
    at org.pawnshop.ui.BillRedemption.BillRedemptionTableMouseReleased(BillRedemption.java:479)
    at org.pawnshop.ui.BillRedemption.access$300(BillRedemption.java:37)
    at org.pawnshop.ui.BillRedemption$4.mouseReleased(BillRedemption.java:356)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:290)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: `There is no button action here only mouse release event.` - this seems to be wrong. You need to work with button action listeners.

Comment: But my project demands only mouse click events. There are no buttons on the form.

Comment: Is it not possible with out buttons?

Comment: Checkbox is a button

Comment: I'm using net beans IDE, to get check boxes in my jTable, I went to jtable properties and selected particular column as Boolean where I need check boxes. I didn't use any buttons as such. if Checkbox is a button can you please explain the logic behind it.

Comment: @trashgod your link is not working. Can somebody help me with the code. My entire project is on halt just for this.

Comment: I've updated my question and screenshots, code and the error message. Please somebody can help with the code.

Comment: As discussed [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), model values of type `Boolean` are rendered and edited with a check box by default, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8739207/230513).

Comment: When I selected 4 rows in T1 they are copied to T2. but when I uncheck the 1st check box in T1 then it deletes the all copied rows in T2.

Comment: You need to store the corresponding boolean data in the `TableModel`. For better guidance, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: isChecked = (Boolean) BillRedemptionTable.getValueAt(rownum[i], 1); isChecked is a Boolean value in which all checked items are stored. If you understood my issue can you please help me with the code part. Thank you @trashgod

Comment: Absent your [mcve], I don't have enough information to respond meaningfully.

Comment: Hi guys I got the answer thanks to everyone