# how to set renderer to checkbox on jtable for row?

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jtable, renderer

1. I set the renderer to the checkbox on jtable using following code

   ```
   Object[] ColumnData = {"Sr No","Ward Name","Total voters","Action"};
   Object[][] RawData=null;
   ```

   **//  in loop**

   model.insertRow(x, new Object[]{ key,ward_name_var,total_vot_var,new Object[]{o}});
     model.setValueAt(o,x,3);
     tblWard.setModel(model);

   Setchk(tblWard,3,checkbox);  // by calling this method  which contains following

   private void Setchk(JTable jTable1, int i, JCheckBox checkbox) 
       {
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer((new CWCheckBoxRenderer()));
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellEditor(new CheckBoxCellEditor());
       }

> Blockquote

how can we try it for row to set the checkbox on jtable.
      thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with 'set a renderer for a row'. The used renderer depends on the data in a specific cell (for example an integer requires a different renderer then a boolean), and this data has the same type in each column. So it only make sense to set a renderer for a column, and not for a row

Answer (score 2):

If your data is of type `Boolean.class`, the [default render](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) will display a checkbox.  To *change* the checkbox in a particular row, you need a corresponding `CellEditor`. The default render/editor are used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7519403/230513); custom components are illustrated [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply override the `getCellRenderer` method of your `JTable` to return the desired renderer for a given row. Example:

```
JTable table = new JTable() {
    TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int column) {
        if (row == checkBoxRow)
            return myCheckBoxRenderer;
        else
            return super.getCellRenderer(row, column);
    }
};
```