# DefaultTableModel doesn't refresh

Tags: java, swing, jtable, refresh, defaulttablemodel

My JTable doesn't refresh after new data is entered into the database. I need to terminate and execute again to see results. I've included DefaultTableModel and fireTableDataChanged. What else did I miss? Thanks!

```
{
    columnNames = new Vector();
    data = new Vector(); 

    try{
        //database stuffs
    }

    catch{
    }  


    DefaultTableModel tm = new DefaultTableModel(); 
    JTable table = new JTable (tm); 
    JScrollPane scrollPane  = new JScrollPane(table);

    table = new JTable(data,columnNames)            
    {               
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){
            return false;
        }        

            public void newDataAvailable (TableModelEvent e){
            }
    };      

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);            
    scrollPane.setBounds(33, 47, 256, 228);      
    panel.add(scrollPane);          

}
```

Can I create a 'Refresh Button' and refresh the values instead?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to invoke `fireTableDataChanged()` explicitly; `DefaultTableModel` does this automatically when you update the model, as shown in this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7519403/230513).

Comment: Thanks. I've removed fireTableDataChanged(), it's not working still. Am I supposed to add newDataAvailable() instead? Data is added directly into the database with PreparedStatement, is that affecting the automatic update?

Comment: After you insert new data in the database and commit the result, you'll need run the original query again to fetch the new rows.

Answer (score 2):

You create new `JTable` instances. Create it just once and set the new model only to the existing `JTable` (added to container properly).

Comment: Thanks. I amended my code but it does not seem to work still. Should I be invoking specific methods to refresh the values? Do I have to validate() or repaint() my JTable?

Answer (score 0):

1. I have made a new project in that I have selected a new frame and drag a table, a label, a text field and a button from the swing controls to your frame.

2.create a table in back-end…

3. Download rs2xml jar file from this link

[Download rs2xml.jar](http://fvmproject.googlecode.com/svn-history/r9/trunk/rs2xml.jar)

4. Add it to the project library…

Right click on the project > properties > library > add Jar/folder > select jar > ok

5.Then connect mysql  using following code

```
public class DBConnect {

Connection connection = null;

public Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");
        System.out.println("connection successfully");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return connection;
}
}
```

6. Call the function in the page using following code

   ```
   con=new DBConnect();
   statement=con.getConnection().createStatement();
   ```

7.Then create a update function type the following code…

```
void update_table() throws SQLException{
    rs=statement.executeQuery("select * from details");
    jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
}
```

8.In the buttons action event type the following and call the update function

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

   try {
       Object name=jTextField1.getText();
       String sql="insert into details (name) values('"+name+"')";
        int  resultset=statement.executeUpdate(sql);
        update_table();
   } catch (SQLException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(update.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
```

}

9.Then run the project…

YOU can also Follow this Tutorial:--

[How to refresh JTable after insert delete or update the data in java Netbeans ID](http://tut.julfi.com/refresh-jtable-insert-delete-update-data-java-netbeans-id/)