# How to release JScrollpane to make it be not always down to the bottom?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I added the following code segment to my project to force the JScrollPane automatically be down to the bottom after the user acting selection performance, however, when I tried to drag the scroll to go to the top, it still is forced to make the scroll down to the bottom, and I want to ask any solution to resolve it? Thanks in advance.

```
private void autoScrollToBottom() {
    sdPanel.getTabScrollPane().getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {

        @Override
        public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
            e.getAdjustable().setValue(e.getAdjustable().getMaximum());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use some boolean flag which will indicate if you should move your scrollbar. Set it to to `true` when you pereform a correct action then in your code:

```
@Override
  public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
  if(isScrollingDownRequired) {
    e.getAdjustable().setValue(e.getAdjustable().getMaximum());
    isScrollingDownRequired = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for `AdjustmentListener`; there's a related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7519403/230513).