# JTable / TableModel MVC Implementation [Help]

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jtable, tablemodel

I'm trying to implement the **MVC** on a test example. How can i update the table when there is a change

**Class: Model**

```java
class valueUpdater extends Thread {
    private String sValue;

    public valueUpdater() {
        this.start();
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.sValue;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
                this.sValue = String.valueOf(i);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Class: Controller**

```java
 public class CLS_Controller2 extends AbstractTableModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5603593230985106202L;
    private String[] sArrColumns = { "Nombre", "Valor" };

    private ArrayList<valueUpdater> tListUpdater = new ArrayList<valueUpdater>();

    public CLS_Controller2() {
        super();
    }

    public void addRow(String sName) {
        this.tListUpdater.add(new valueUpdater(sName));
        this.fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public void deleteRow(int iIndex) {
        this.tListUpdater.remove(iIndex);
        this.fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int iColumn) {
        return this.sArrColumns[iColumn];
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return this.sArrColumns.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return this.tListUpdater.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int iRow, int iColumn) {
        valueUpdater tValueUpdater = this.tListUpdater.get(iRow);

        switch (iColumn) {
        case 0:
            return tValueUpdater.getRowName();
        case 1:
            return tValueUpdater.getValue();
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object oValue, int iRow, int iColumn) {
        valueUpdater tValueUpdater = this.tListUpdater.get(iRow);

        switch (iColumn) {
        case 0:
            tValueUpdater.setRowName(oValue.toString());
            break;
        }

        fireTableCellUpdated(iRow, iColumn);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<String> getColumnClass(int iColumn) {
        return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Class: View**

```java
public class FRM_Main {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTable table;
    private CLS_Controller2 tModel;
    private JTextField textField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    FRM_Main window = new FRM_Main();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public FRM_Main() {
        try {
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 476, 283);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Add");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                tModel.addRow(textField.getText());
            }
        });

        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Delete");

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setColumns(10);
        GroupLayout gl_panel = new GroupLayout(panel);
        gl_panel.setHorizontalGroup(gl_panel
                .createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(
                        gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addGroup(
                                        gl_panel.createParallelGroup(
                                                Alignment.LEADING)
                                                .addComponent(
                                                        scrollPane,
                                                        GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                        440, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                .addGroup(
                                                        Alignment.TRAILING,
                                                        gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                        textField,
                                                                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                                        GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                .addPreferredGap(
                                                                        ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                        btnNewButton)
                                                                .addPreferredGap(
                                                                        ComponentPlacement.RELATED,
                                                                        216,
                                                                        Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                        btnNewButton_1)))
                                .addContainerGap()));
        gl_panel.setVerticalGroup(gl_panel
                .createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(
                        gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addComponent(scrollPane,
                                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 194,
                                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(
                                        gl_panel.createParallelGroup(
                                                Alignment.BASELINE)
                                                .addComponent(btnNewButton_1)
                                                .addComponent(
                                                        textField,
                                                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                        GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addComponent(btnNewButton))
                                .addContainerGap(80, Short.MAX_VALUE)));

        table = new JTable();
        table.setShowVerticalLines(false);
        table.setShowHorizontalLines(false);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        tModel = new CLS_Controller2();
        table.setModel(tModel);

        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
        panel.setLayout(gl_panel);
    }
}
```

I have read a lot about MVC but I'm still new. If someone can help me please. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually your `TableModel` should contain all the data. Any operation say `insert, delete, update` all should be done in the `TableModel` itself.\

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand what you want to say. I need to update the TableModel with ArrayList<valueupdate> values but i dont know how implement that.

Comment: Get the row number where you are updating and then use `setValueAt` method to update the data.

Comment: Sorry but did you read the topic ? i need automatically update and not manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `TableModel` is the *model*, and your `JTable` is the *view*. The call to `setModel()` causes the view to add itself as a `TableModelListener` to the model; subsequent changes to the model notify the view to update itself based on any `TableModelEvent` received. In this complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7519403/230513), both a button and a separate thread update the model. `SwingWorker`, seen [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#publish%28V...%29), is another common approach that simplifies synchronizing access to shared data.

A noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513), Swing uses separable model architecture, with the user controlling interaction. Except for the initial wiring, there isn't much for your controller to do.

[image]