# Java JTable to be refreshed every 2 seconds

Tags: java, swing, timer, jtable

Hy! I am working on java app that has 2 forms. In first form my user order meals and I store his order in my database on localhost server. On second form that orders in JTable by using simple sql query. Now I want to make that my JTable is refreshed every 2 seconds, so I can automatically see when user order meal. I tried with Timers, but I am total newbie in Java programming so I would appreciate help... Here is my method that refreshes table but I just need a bit help about Timer:

```
private void NapraviTablicu() {
    dohvatiNarudzbe(); //method for executing sql queries and filling my list KuhinjaListaJela with new ordered meals
    TableModel tableModel = new KitchenTableModel(KuhinjaListaJela);//Making new table model from list
    Tablica.setModel(tableModel);// displaying new meals in table
}
```

Comment: Consider showing us your timer code and explaining how it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

A `javax.swing.Timer` is a little awkward for this; as is `java.util.Timer`. As long as you update your `TableModel` on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), you can query the database on another thread every two seconds using either approach cited below. Note that it's OK to sleep on a background thread.

- `SwingWorker`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).
- `Runnable`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7519403/230513).