# Create dynamic table to add new entry with button

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, jtable, dynamic-tables

I am trying to build a register, so that when a button is clicked, a new entry appears on a table. Ideally, I am looking to build a table on the left side of the screen, with two rows and new column appears when the button is clicked. I want the table to have a fixed size, but it should be scrollable after a certain amount of entries. So far, I have created and formatted the `JButton` objects that I want to be clicked for a new entry to appear. I also know that I should use a `JTable` to pursue this.

How should I go about making this dynamic table?

Code So Far:

```
private void addRegister(JPanel pane) {

             JPanel everythingPane = new JPanel();
             JPanel pluPane = new JPanel();

             Dimension button = new Dimension(200,150);

             JTable pluTable = new JTable();


             JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();

             buttonPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

             //JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel (new FlowLayout (FlowLayout.LEFT));

             JPanel subPane1 = new JPanel();
             subPane1.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
             JPanel subPane2 = new JPanel();
             subPane2.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
             JPanel subPane3 = new JPanel();
             subPane3.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
             JPanel subPane4 = new JPanel();
             subPane4.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
             JPanel subPane5 = new JPanel();
             subPane5.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
             JPanel alignmentLayer = new JPanel();

             JButton frappuccino = new JButton("Frappuccino");
             JButton icedCoffee = new JButton("Iced Coffee");
             frappuccino.setPreferredSize(button);
             icedCoffee.setPreferredSize(button);

             JButton arizona = new JButton("Arizona Green Tea");
             JButton izze = new JButton("Izze");
             arizona.setPreferredSize(button);
             izze.setPreferredSize(button);

             JButton snapple = new JButton("Snapple");
             JButton gatorade = new JButton("Gatorade");
             snapple.setPreferredSize(button);
             gatorade.setPreferredSize(button);

             JButton water = new JButton("Water");
             JButton appleJuice = new JButton("Apple Juice");
             water.setPreferredSize(button);
             appleJuice.setPreferredSize(button);

             JButton orangeJuice = new JButton("Orange Juice");
             JButton mentos = new JButton("Mentos");
             orangeJuice.setPreferredSize(button);
             mentos.setPreferredSize(button);

             JButton gum = new JButton("Gum");
             JButton cliffBar = new JButton("Cliff Bar");
             gum.setPreferredSize(button);
             cliffBar.setPreferredSize(button);

             JButton littleBites = new JButton("Little Bites");
             JButton welchs = new JButton("Welch's Fruit Snacks");
             littleBites.setPreferredSize(button);
             welchs.setPreferredSize(button);

             JButton fiberOneBar = new JButton("Fiber One Bar");
             JButton fiberOneBrownie = new JButton("Fiber One Brownie");
             fiberOneBar.setPreferredSize(button);
             fiberOneBrownie.setPreferredSize(button);

             JButton cheezeIts = new JButton("Cheeze Its");
             JButton goldFish = new JButton("Gold Fish");
             cheezeIts.setPreferredSize(button);
             goldFish.setPreferredSize(button);

             JButton teaBag = new JButton("Tea Bag");
             JButton poptarts = new JButton("Poptarts");
             teaBag.setPreferredSize(button);
             poptarts.setPreferredSize(button);

             JButton sampleButton = new JButton("Sample Button");
             JButton sampleButton2 = new JButton("Sample Button");
             sampleButton.setPreferredSize(button);
             sampleButton2.setPreferredSize(button);

             JButton sampleButton3 = new JButton("Sample Button");
             JButton sampleButton4 = new JButton("Sample Button");
             sampleButton3.setPreferredSize(button);
             sampleButton4.setPreferredSize(button);


             subPane1.add(frappuccino);
             subPane1.add(icedCoffee);

             subPane1.add(arizona);
             subPane1.add(izze);

             subPane2.add(snapple);
             subPane2.add(gatorade);

             subPane2.add(water);
             subPane2.add(appleJuice);

             subPane3.add(orangeJuice);
             subPane3.add(mentos);

             subPane3.add(gum);
             subPane3.add(cliffBar);

             subPane4.add(littleBites);
             subPane4.add(welchs);

             subPane4.add(fiberOneBar);
             subPane4.add(fiberOneBrownie);

             subPane5.add(cheezeIts);
             subPane5.add(goldFish);

             subPane5.add(teaBag);
             subPane5.add(poptarts);             

             alignmentLayer.add(sampleButton);
             alignmentLayer.add(sampleButton2);
             alignmentLayer.add(sampleButton3);
             alignmentLayer.add(sampleButton4);


             buttonPane.add(subPane1);
             buttonPane.add(subPane2);
             buttonPane.add(subPane3);
             buttonPane.add(subPane4);
             buttonPane.add(subPane5);
             buttonPane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,100)));
             buttonPane.add(alignmentLayer);


             pluPane.add(pluTable);

             everythingPane.add(pluPane);
             everythingPane.add(buttonPane);

             pane.add(everythingPane);

      }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Note that trashgod's SSCCE is shorter than the uncompilable code snippet seen in the question.

Comment: You can experiment with `addRow()` and `addColumn()` in this [sscce](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19472190/230513).

Answer (score 13):

`JTable` is more commonly used in a way that adds *rows*, rather than *columns*. I re-factored this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7519403/230513) to illustrate the basic idea below. Each time the button is clicked, a new row is added to the table's model, which updates the table itself.

[image: add table]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentEvent;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19472190/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7519403/230513
 */
 public class TableAddTest extends JPanel {

    private static final int N_ROWS = 8;
    private static String[] header = {"ID", "String", "Number", "Boolean"};
    private DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(null, header) {

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
            return getValueAt(0, col).getClass();
        }
    };
    private JTable table = new JTable(dtm);
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    private JScrollBar vScroll = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
    private int row;
    private boolean isAutoScroll;

    public TableAddTest() {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Dimension d = new Dimension(320, N_ROWS * table.getRowHeight());
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(d);
        for (int i = 0; i < N_ROWS; i++) {
            addRow();
        }
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        vScroll.addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {

            @Override
            public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
                isAutoScroll = !e.getValueIsAdjusting();
            }
        });
        this.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Add Row") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                addRow();
            }
        }));
        this.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private void addRow() {
        char c = (char) ('A' + row++ % 26);
        dtm.addRow(new Object[]{
                Character.valueOf(c),
                String.valueOf(c) + String.valueOf(row),
                Integer.valueOf(row),
                Boolean.valueOf(row % 2 == 0)
            });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                TableAddTest nlt = new TableAddTest();
                f.add(nlt);
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```