# Return Object array method

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, swing, jtable

I just can't seem to return the variable `data` in this method:

```
public Object[] populateTable(ArrayList<Outlet> outletList, String selection){ 
    Object[] data;
    for(int i = 0; i<outletList.size(); i++){
        if(outletList.get(i).getCity().equalsIgnoreCase(selection)){
            if(outletList.get(i).getStatus().equals("ACTIVE")){

                String bar = outletList.get(i).getBarangay();
                String code = Integer.toString(outletList.get(i).getCode());
                String name = outletList.get(i).getName();

                data = {bar, code, name};                      
            }   
        }               
    }
    return data;
}
```

Netbeans is saying illegal start of expression. Is there a way to execute this method wherein data (coming from a mysql database transferred to a `ArrayList<object>` in an interface) is passed to an `Object[]`? Finding a way to populate `JTable` rows with data coming from a mysql database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error arises here:

```
data = {bar, code, name};
```

Instead, construct a new array of `Object` to hold instances of `String`:

```
data = new Object[]{bar, code, name};
```

Then you can invoke `addRow(data)` on your `DefaultTableModel`. A complete example is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19472190/230513) in `TableAddTest#addRow()`.

[image]

Comment: See also [*Arrays: Creating, Initializing, and Accessing an Array*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).