# Synchronyzed elements deletion on JTable-linked-model to avoid NullPointerExceptions?

Tags: java, swing, events, concurrency, jtable

I'm quite sure this problem has a simple solution, but I haven't been able to solve it.

Scenario:

1) I have a JTable linked to a model based on a LinkedHashMap with (for example) 10 elements.

2) External events delete the first 2 elements almost at the same time, so:

2.1) The model deletes element #0, and throws an event like "row linked to element #0, it is, row #0, has changed".

2.2) **Before the JTable has time to be modified, the second element is deleted on the model** and the event launched is the same, because the second element is now the first one.

3) The JTable processes both events "row #0 has been deleted".

I think this is why I am getting a "NULL error" like the following one:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at paneles.panel_positions.Elements_Manager.getValueAt(Elements_Manager.java:388)
    at paneles.panel_positions.Elements_Manager$1Dates_Renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(Positions_Manager.java:891)
    at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5736)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(BasicTableUI.java:2114)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(BasicTableUI.java:2016)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(BasicTableUI.java:1812)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:731)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5230)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1249)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5178)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4989)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:808)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:796)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:796)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:769)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:718)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(RepaintManager.java:62)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1677)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I've been thinking on any kind of synchronized mechanism so the second deletion can't be executed until the first one had been finished and executed the event on the JTable, but I can't figure it out which would be the correct way of doing this.

This is happening on a real time-events-processing app, so forcing the events source to wait in this way doesn't seem to be a good solution, but I can't figure it out a correct way of doing it. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Method on another thread that launches deletions:

```
public void delete_all_elements() {

cloned_model = mainobject.getCloned_model();

for (Element pos_aux : cloned_model.values()) {
        notify_pos_to_be_deleted(pos_aux);
    }
}
```

Code executed on the thread wich receives the previous message on a messages-queue:

```
...
model.rmv(row_index);
TableModelEvent event = new TableModelEvent (this, row_index, total_rows-1, TableModelEvent.ALL_COLUMNS, TableModelEvent.DELETE);
notify_suscriptors(event);
...
```

Code of notify_suscriptors:

```
...
((TableModelListener)listeners.get(i)).tableChanged(event);
...
```

Comment: share your relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must update your `Table Model` *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). Use `EventQueue.invokeLater()`, as shown in this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7519403/230513).

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // remove row
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, so, if I've got it right, the thread wich makes the model modification, wich right now is a simple "Runnable" with a while waiting for new orders, should be modified in the way you show me. Sounds like it could work; I'll try it right now.

Comment: Now I'm detecting an unexpected increment on the RAM used by the main app (not an alarming one (179MB -> 184MB), just not understood at this moment, I'll have to study it), but the problem with the NULL pointer has been solved. Perfectly solved trashgod, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Glad to help; using a [profiler](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) may be helpful; `DefaultTableModel` may be a [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25526869/230513).

Comment: Great. Another deserved +1 on your http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime  helping answer :)